# Could not load php_curl

Tags: php, windows, curl

I have installed php5.2.13, apache2.2.15 on WindowsXp.Add C:\php to PATH ssystem variable.

I can't enable curl extension. I configure extension_dir and remove ";" form php_curl in php.ini but nothing!

I copied ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in system32 directory - nothing
Error log say: 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - Attempt to access invalid address.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Can someone help me?

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: I suppose you have already checked, but does C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll exist?

Comment: sure. 

One more: I installed php manualy, Apache - with installer. But when I installed XAMPP - curl worked

But I don't want to use XAMPP, so I search solution for my problem...

Comment: try to take a look at this to check the whole process http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/install.html

Comment: this is what I did the first - not working

Comment: may be something wrong with ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll for this version of php?

when I enable openssl extension - the same error

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution : mod_ssl was disabled in http.conf.

I remove dll files from system32 directory and everything is ok.

So, just need to enable curl extension in php.ini. And enable mod_ssl in httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

As weird as it may seem, just enabling mod_ssl extension in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule ssl_module C:\YOUR\PATH\apache-2.2\modules\mod_ssl.so
```

resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after upgrading from PHP 7.2 to 7.3.

The solution was to download a new version of Apache from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/. The new Apache/bin had libcurl.dll.